# How do I solve the error "Insufficient permisssions" when using vscode?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, visual-studio-code

I'm a new user of Ubuntu. I have installed vs code using:

```
sudo snap install --classic code
```

But I can't use it.  For example, when I try to create a file I get the error:

```
Unable to write file '/opt/lampp/htdocs/' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied
```

When I try to save a file after editing, it shows the error:

```
Failed to save 'index.php': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.
```

But I can fix this by clicking on retry as sudo.  Is there anyway to stop both of these errors permanently?

Comment: Please add how (and from what source) you've installed Visual Studio Code please.

Comment: sudo snap install --classic code

Comment: Well, that's your problem. I'm not familiar with snaps, but you need to grant permissions for snaps. Maybe this can be done from Ubuntu's own Snap Store.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grant the required permissions for this snap by following these instructions: [Guide to snap permissions](https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-guide-to-snap-permissions-and-interfaces). You could also remove the snap and use Microsofts .deb Package to avoid these problems.